# jQuery - Show div when radio button is selected and text field is populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I need to show a hidden div when a radio button is selected and a text field has input. Right now my script shows the hidden div when text is entered into the text field. Can someone help me adjust my script so that it also requires the radio button to be selected before showing the div? I need two conditions met before the div should be displayed.

```
<!--RADIO BUTTON-->
<input name="term" type="radio" id="promoPrice">
<strong>$XX.XX</strong>
<div class="promoPrice1" style="display: none;">
<img src="images/x.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"> <span style="padding-left: 5px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 18px; vertical-align: middle;">$XX.XX</span>
</div>

<!--TEXT INPUT BOX-->
<input type="text" placeholder="Promo Code" class="promo" style="width: 175px;">

<!--JQUERY SCRIPT-->
<script type="text/javascript">
//PROMO CODE
$(function () {
$(".promo").bind("change keyup input",function() { 
    var show_promo = true;
    $('.promo').each( function(i) {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0)  {
            show_promo = false;
        } 
    });
    if (show_promo){
            $(".promoPrice1").hide();
    } else {
            $(".promoPrice1").show();
    }
});
});
//END PROMO CODE
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if($(this).val().length > 0)
```

to

```
if(($(this).val().length > 0) && $("#promoPrice").is(':checked'))
```

and add

```
$("#promoPrice").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked') && $('.promo').val().length>0){
    $(".promoPrice1").show();
    }
});
```

working fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/ccv84nc0/1/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried something like this initially, but I couldn't get it to work. This unfortunately doesn't seem to be working for me either.

Comment: @user1605791: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ccv84nc0/) is a working example at fiddle. Are you sure you you don't have any other errors in code?

Comment: @user1605791 : if you want radio .click also to be handled , check this updated fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/ccv84nc0/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ccv84nc0/1/)

Comment: Thanks so much. When I had initially pasted your update I somehow included an underscore after the "length > 0". I did have one more quick question- is it possible to have the image disappear if i add another radio button and that button is clicked?

Comment: @user1605791 , just like the first radio button, bind function to hide div on 2nd radio oncick, `$("#promoPriceTohide").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked') ){
    $(".promoPrice1").hide();
    }
});`    -    and I hope that only one of the radio button will be selected at a time, so you won't need change in  `if(($(this).val().length > 0) && $("#promoPrice").is(':checked'))`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've created a fiddle with the three radio buttons at https://jsfiddle.net/d00dkirk/ptegzw7y/. Would you mind taking a look? I'm wanting to have the price disappear and the new price appear when another radio button is clicked.

Comment: @user1605791 check [https://jsfiddle.net/ptegzw7y/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/ptegzw7y/1/)